# Remove Caption Reference First Page when appearing in LoF

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, back-referencing

I have a citation in a caption and in my biblography it lists the pages each reference is in. However it lists the page of my List of Figures (`ix`), but I'd like to remove that. Is there a way to remove part of the caption when putting it in the LoF or to not include prefatory pages in the reference page list?

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1}
  \caption{caption is here (adapted from \cite{reference1}).}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `caption`: `\caption[caption is here for TOC]{caption is here (adapted from \cite{reference1}).}` -- Maybe you are interested in the package [`notoccite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/notoccite)

Comment: Thanks, saw somebody hint at that but missed the significance. However, their order in the Bibliography is still using the LoF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `caption` as most other level commands has an optional argument which is used for TOC, LOF or LOT:

```
\caption[caption for TOC]{caption here}
```

The request of using \cite inside captions is very often. Donald Arsenau wrote a package do simplify the process: [notoccite](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/notoccite)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{foo}
Text \cite{article-full}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \caption{caption \cite{book-full}}
\end{figure}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```